# Type error : Cannot read property 'python' of null

Tags: r, error-handling, rstudio, rtools

I have installed the recent R version 4.2.1, rtools version 42 and recent R Studio version. But after installing all these in my system.
When I am trying to open the new project, it will show the following error,
`Type error: Cannot read property 'python' of null`.
I don't know how to set path for this version of R and in the new features of R 4.2.1 webpage, they have mentioned that no need of setting the path from the user.
So please help how to fix this error.

Comment: what is your new project called?

Comment: In top right side corner, currently it is showing `Project (None)`. If I click New Project, it is showing that error...

Comment: Apparently RStudio fails to detect if python is installed? I would install python or contact the RStudio support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the issue was tied to the new Quarto publishing platform on win 11.

I was able to fix it by installing Python and reinstalling Quarto to a path that had no empty space, e.g. *"C:\Quarto"*. Installation in *"C:\Program Files"* was causing issues.